When is 明日(あした) clearly 平板型?
(This post only concerns 標準語.)
I always thought that 明日{あした} was simply 尾高型, but when I look it up in the dictionary (大辞林), it says that it is 尾高型 as a noun and 平板型 adverbially.
This is a bit confusing to me because I thought, in the cases where it is used adverbially, it's impossible to distinguish between 尾高型 and 平板型 anyway.
I'd be interested in example sentences where pronouncing 明日{あした} as 尾高型 would be incorrect (明日{あした}の… doesn't count).

It may be just a custom to mark a word as 平板 when it never causes a downstep. This question may have been asking that.

Good question. Think of the following sentence:

あした{LHH}、旅行に行くんだ。

You can put final particles in the middle of sentence, at any boundary between syntactic words (文節). Let's fill in ね, which inherits accent pattern of the previous word.

あしたね{LHHH}、旅行に行くんだ。

Compare with the noun usage:

旅行に行くのは[あしたね]{LHHL}。

